# Python - Generadores para desempaquetar diccionarios en una sola línea

Tags: python, python-3.x, diccionarios, generator

Les traigo una cuestión que a buen seguro tendrá una solución evidente, pero por más vueltas que le doy no consigo enfocar correctamente el problema.

Tenemos un diccionario en Python cuya longitud no conocemos (y aun conociéndola, no nos serviría para el caso) y precisamente por ser un diccionario tampoco podemos tener en cuenta el orden en el que aparecen los elementos.

Se necesitaría reproducir todo el contenido del diccionario en una sola línea, teniendo en cuenta que *el código en la 1ª línea debería ser el mismo que en la 5ª* (**los cambios de longitud en el diccionario no afectan al texto que se produce**):

```
fiz = {'Partido Ultra':23792, 'Partido Mega':14959, 'Partido Super':7755, 'Partido Maxi':5054, 'Partido Parguela':4508}
print('Los resultados de las elecciones fueron:{}, {} votos, {}, {} votos, {}, {} votos, {}, {} votos, {}, {} votos, {}, {} votos.'.format(...))

fiz['Partido Über'] = 2176
fiz['Partido Alles'] = 30001
print('Los resultados de las elecciones fueron:{}, {} votos,{}, {} votos,{}, {} votos,{}, {} votos,{}, {} votos,{}, {} votos,{}, {} votos,.'.format(...))
```

La solución más obvia pasaría por crear una lista que a su vez nos sirva como base para formar la cadena de texto y después extenderla para cada par clave-valor, pero la descarto por tremendamente ineficiente a medida que aumenta `len(fiz)`. Precisamente el interés de la pregunta radica en **la manera de iterar sobre varios elementos cuando no se puede o no se cree conveniente definir un orden**.

¿Sería necesario crear una función para extender el texto indefinidamente? O por el contrario se podría recurrir a herramientas iterativas (p.ej. generadores; en caso de que sean aplicables).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

¿Será esto lo que buscas?

```
fiz = {'Partido Ultra':23792, 'Partido Mega':14959, 'Partido Super':7755, 'Partido Maxi':5054, 'Partido Parguela':4508}


print("Los resultados de las elecciones fueron:",
     ",".join("{}, {}votos".format(k,v) for k,v in fiz.items()))
```

Resultado (una larga línea):

```html
Los resultados de las elecciones fueron: Partido Ultra, 23792votos,Partido Mega, 14959votos,Partido Super, 7755votos,Partido Maxi, 5054votos,Partido Parguela, 4508votos
```

Nota que he respetado tu espaciado, en el que (no entiendo por qué) no pones espacios detrás de las comas, ni separas el número de votos de la palabra "votos", además de que usas el mismo separador (la coma) para separar entre sí los partidos o los partidos de sus votos, todo lo cual hace muy ilegible el resultado.

En mi opinión, esto queda mejor:

```
print("Los resultados de las elecciones fueron:",
     "; ".join("{}, {} votos".format(k,v) for k,v in fiz.items()))
```

```html
Los resultados de las elecciones fueron: Partido Ultra, 23792 votos; Partido Mega, 14959 votos; Partido Super, 7755 votos; Partido Maxi, 5054 votos; Partido Parguela, 4508 votos
```

Comment: No, tienes toda la razón, es un error. Paso a corregirlo.

Comment: Desconocía que los métodos `.format` y `.join` pudiera utilizarse junto con generadores. Excelente síntesis.

Comment: Me respondo a mí mismo después de algunas búsquedas: Por regla general se deben utilizar `*args` (si es una lista) o `**kwargs` (si es un diccionario).

Comment: @RubenGarcíaTutor Pero en qué contexto usarías `**` para este caso? Eso para cuando tienes un diccionario cuyas claves son nombres de parámetros y quieres pasarlo a una función. Por ejemplo, si tienes una función que admitiría esta sintaxis `foo(a=1, b=2)`, y tienes un dccionario `d={'a': 1, 'b': 2}`, entonces puedes llamar a la función así: `foo(**d)`. Pero no veo qué relación hay entre esto y lo de imprimir el diccionario en una sola línea...

Comment: Porque en algunas situaciones el texto se tiene que procesar en mitad de la cadena, y no al final . Por ejemplo, digamos que tengo varios diccionarios con el formato: `FR8162 = {'Londres Stansted':'7:19', 'Málaga':'11:22'}` y una cadena: `"El vuelo {} salió del aeropuerto {} a las {} y aterrizó en el aeropuerto de {} a las {}."`

Comment: @RubenGarcíaTutor Pues en ese caso tampoco te vale usar `.format(**FR8162)` ya que en ese caso básicamente estás haciendo: `cadena.format(Londres Stansted='7:19', Málaga=`11:22`)`  tampoco haría lo que esperas, entre otras cosas porque pasas dos parámetros cuando la cadena de formato tiene cuatro "lugares".

Comment: Para este caso que planteas lo más parecido a una solución sería esto: `"El vuelo FR8162 salió del aeropuerto {0[0]} a las {0[1]} y aterrizó en el aeropuerto de {1[0]} a las {1[1]}.".format(*FR8162.items())` Pero no me gusta mucho porque la cadena de formato debe conocer cuántos elementos tiene el diccionario. Creo que esto es muy diferente de lo que preguntabas inicialmente. Quizás quieras abrir otra pregunta

Comment: Quizá el ejemplo no fuera bueno y debería haber puesto otro, pero yo creo que la pregunta es la misma: Cómo formatear una cadena de texto con los elementos (pares clave-valor) de un diccionario, cuando no puedes apoyarte en argumentos posicionales.

Comment: @RubenGarcíaTutor Entonces quizás no la había entendido yo bien en primer lugar. Yo entendí que querías volcar un diccionario cuyo número de elementos no conoces de antemano. Eso encaja con el ejemplo que aparecía en la pregunta, pero no con el que pusiste en el comentario. ¿Entiendo entonces que sí que conoces de antemano el tamaño del diccionario? ¿O que la cadena de formato sólo quiere mostrar ciertas claves aunque el diccionario tenga más? Y en ese caso, supongo que sabes los nombres de las claves a mostrar, ya que de otro modo ¿cómo las especificarías? (por posición no puede ser...)

Comment: El problema con `len(fiz)` (en el ejemplo de la pregunta) no es que no la conozcas, _sino que puede cambiar_ , y eso te obliga a añadir más o menos `{}` para formatear a medida que esa logitud aumenta o disminuye. Volviendo al ejemplo de los aviones, yo creo que sí existe una relación, porque **en un caso y en el otro estamos leyendo matrices** , ya sea for filas o por columnas. Y, entonces, sería: `"El vuelo {} salió del aeropuerto {} a las {} y el vuelo {} salió del aeropuerto {} a las {} y el vuelo {}...."` , etcétera, y después otra fila para los aeropuertos y horas de llegada.